# Continuous ping loop in script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ping

I am working on some custom Openwrt compilation. Some of my scripts do ping for testing connection before doing their stuff.

```
if [ "$(ping -c 1 -w 3 8.8.8.8)" ]; then
  do stuff;
else
 echo "no connection"
fi
```

Some of them run other ones and because `ping` takes some time, running scripts takes more time than it should which is a problem in some cases.

I would like to make some kind of continuous loop which writes 0 or 1 to some file. From now on, scripts which use ping for connection testing will test what is in `somefile`.

Is there a way to write such script?

Answer (score 12):

Do you mean something as simple as this:

```
while :; do
   ping -c 1 -w 3 8.8.8.8; echo $? > /tmp/ping.status
   sleep 1
done
```

That will write the exit status of `ping` to `/tmp/ping.status` once a second. Then, in another script, you could have something like:

```
pingFailed=$(cat /tmp/ping.status)
if [ $pingFailed -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "No connection"
else
    echo "Connected!"
fi
```

So yes, you could do this. However, it is a really bad method of checking your connection. Obviously, there are race conditions here. That the connection was active when the first loop ran, doesn't mean it is active this second. More importantly, if you read the `ping.status` file at the start of the script, that doesn't mean the connection will still be there at the end of it. In addition, you are spamming both your network and your CPU with continuous requests. This is really not very elegant.

A faster and simpler way of testing if your connection is up (at least on Linux) is looking at `/sys/class/net/$NIC/link_mode` where `$NIC` is the name of your network card. For example, on my system:

```
## Wireless connection up
$ cat /sys/class/net/wlp3s0/link_mode 
1
## Wireless connection down
$ cat /sys/class/net/wlp3s0/link_mode 
0
```

You can write a function that checks this:

```
isLinkDown(){
    return $(cat /sys/class/net/wlp3s0/link_mode)
}
```

And you can use it in your scripts like this:

```
if isLinkDown; then 
    echo Link Down
else
    echo Link Up
```

Comment: Nice tip with the `link_mode`.

Comment: Ive tried link_mode in the past but i dont know why it doesnt work as it should for me. For example my device has only 3g modem on, no wifi or cable connection. Everything is working fine but cat /sys/class/net/3g-modem/link_mode returns 0.

Comment: @180doman huh, that's strange. Maybe ping is simpler then.

Comment: I like this approach, but just increase `sleep 1` to something like `sleep 500` and then don't check as often to reduce usage. Tweak to desired needs.

Answer (score 3):

terdon's answer is good but I would avoid that network bloat,

but first an **aside**; `ping` can take as little as 0.002s to 8.8.8.8 so if you want to test a low latency network,

```
$ timeout 0.1 ping -c 1 8.8.8.8
```

can be used to guarantee 1/10 of a second test time (because ping does not have sub second wait times).

Now the **answer** to optimizing speed and network usage; you should make your scripts pass parameters;

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 [OPTIONS]"
    echo " OPTIONS:"
    echo "  -h     this Help message"
    echo "  -n     do Not re-test network connectivity"
}

NO_TEST=false
while getopts "nh" OPT; do
    case "$OPT" in
        n)
            NO_TEST=true
            ;;
        h)
            usage
            exit 0
            ;;
        *)
            echo "unsupported option $OPT" >&2
            usage
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

if ! $NO_TEST && ! ping -c 1 -w 3 8.8.8.8; then
    echo "no connection" >&2
    exit 2
fi
echo "do stuff";
```

Comment: ping can take much longer than that, eg, if you have satellite internet. it's closer to 0.041s here on a fibre connection.

Comment: "ping should only take 0.014s to 8.8.8.8" citation needed. What do you base that on? How do you know where the OP is and what quality connection they have? I tend to have ~28ms to ping to 8.8.8.8 but also see spikes of 152ms or more. And can see much more if the network happens to be slower.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I still think that's way too low, but it might work for some super networks, I guess. On my home connection (non-fiber, ADSL, in London) your ping fails ~1 out of every 5 attempts.

Comment: @terdon both rackspace and amazon have down to 2ms connections to 8.8.8.8 (likely some on site google hardware) depending on the data center. My home connection (slow coaxial cable) has a 9ms connection to 8.8.8.8 (good isp peering)... I'm not sure if there is a global ping overview like https://www.dslreports.com/speedtest/results/country but anyway it's just an aside if any reader is interested in testing for under 1000ms.

Comment: To add some numbers to @Jasen's comment above: with satellite internet via a geostationary satellite, the speed of light alone (and that is assuming no processing delay, no routing, no nothing, just the pure electromagnetic signal propagation) puts the *lower* limit at ~480ms!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all answers! I just need some time to take some of your valuable thoughts into consideration. To clarify some things i just want to add that:
1. I cant use parameters as most of those scripts work either in init.d or are run by cron.
2. The whole idea mainly is being created for modem connection. And ping latencies depend on signal strength. Im not even sure can i lower down ping check interval beyond 1s to have reliable checks when signal strength is low, but connection still exists. That why i thought that ping loop with default interval which just outputs result to some easily accessible place would be best compromise.

This is what i used very recently

```
modemup(){
    echo -e "AT+QRST=1,0\r\n" > /dev/ttyUSB2
    ifdown $INTERFACE && ifup $INTERFACE

    if [ "$(ifconfig | grep $INTFC_NAME)" ]; then
        return 0
    else
        echo "Cant start modem interface"
        return 1
    fi
  } 

reconnect(){
    MAX_ATTEMPTS=$1 #number of tries before reboot
    TRIES=1

    while [ $TRIES -le $MAX_ATTEMPTS ]; do
        echo "Trying to reconnect ..."
        echo "Number of try: $TRIES"
        modemup
        /etc/init.d/network restart
        sleep 10
        if [ "$(ping -c 1 -w 3 8.8.8.8)" ]; then
            break
        fi
        : $((TRIES+=1))
    done
    echo "Tried $MAX_ATTEMPTS times, couldnt reconnect. Rebooting ..."
    reboot
}

while true; do
    if [ "$(ping -c 1 -w 3 8.8.8.8)" ]; then
         rm -rf $NOCONFILE #if noconnection file exists delete it
    else
        mkdir -p $LOG_DIR/${DAY_DIR}
        TIME=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
        echo "$TIME: Connection lost" 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG_FILE
        touch $NOCONFILE
        reconnect $ATTEMPTS 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG_FILE   
    fi
    sleep $INTERVAL
done
```

Comment: You can totally use parameters in init.d and cron, you should https://www.shellcheck.net/ to clean up that script.

Comment: Also you should likley be using a network event instead of a cron every minute; https://askubuntu.com/questions/258580/how-to-run-a-script-depending-on-internet-connection